# Laravel 5 Route Chaining Multiple Models/Controllers

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and want to ask how can I setup the route of my website. Using route resource I'll get the URIs like this.

```
http://www.example.com/products // List all the products
http://www.example.com/products/create // Display a form to create a product
...
And so on...
```

What I was trying to accomplish is, when I visit a single product and click its category my route should look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/products/{slug}/category/{slug}
```

OR

```
http://www.example.com/{productsSlug}/{categorySlug}
```

My routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('home', 'PagesController@home');

Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. This is called *nested routing*:

```
Route::resource('products.category', 'ProductsCategoryController');
```

Then the methods in that controller will just receive the product id/slug as first argument and the category id/slug (if available) as second. For example:

```
public function index($productSlug){}

public function show($productSlug, $categorySlug){}
```

[Laravel Docs - RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: BTW how about when I like to remove the products in the uri  like this http://www.example.com/{productSlug}/{categorySlug}. Is It possible?

Comment: Yes but not with resource routes. You would just need to add the route manually. Note that a dynamic first segment can be dangerous because it catches all requests. If you where to add that you should place the route at the very end/bottom of your routes file.